# angular REST get ID only from call

Tags: angular, rest, api, typescript, get

I want to do a call then get the ID from that call and use it in some code later
but how do I only get the ServiceProvider number? this is what I get from my rest call:

```
     {"mitId": 18,
     "ServiceProvider": "2"}
```

this is my current call

```
  GetServiceProviderId() {
    var spid = this.http.get<Info>(this.rooturl + 'info', { headers: this.reqHeader})

    return spid;
  }
```

So I want to use the ServiceProvideNumber in another call but how do I only return the 2?

Comment: is mitId the id you're trying to access? or are you trying to access field ServiceProvider?

Comment: I want to get ServiceProvider so I want the "2" returned from this call
sorry super new to angular

Comment: What about `return spid.ServiceProvider`?

Comment: so if that result above is a json string, you may need to convert it to a js object using JSON.parse(jsonString) . then access it the way @Programmer mentioned

Comment: @OleBark did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
  GetServiceProviderId(): Observable<Info> {
    return this.http.get<Info>(this.rooturl + 'info', { headers: this.reqHeader })
  }
```

this just returns the json request I then will use pipe and flatmap to get the '2'

```
  GetInstallation(): Observable<Installation[]> {
    return this.GetServiceProviderId().pipe(
      flatMap(info => {
        return this.http.get<Installation[]>
          (this.rooturl +
          "url/?serviceproviderid=" +
          info.ServiceProviderId
      })
    )
  }
```

this will make the call api/url/?serviceproviderid=2

Answer (score 1):

Return observable from method `GetServiceProviderId` as:

```
GetServiceProviderId() {
    return this.http.get<Info>(this.rooturl + 'info', { headers: this.reqHeader});
}
```

Subscribe to consume value from response wherever you want as:

```
GetServiceProviderId.subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    //here you will get id
})
```